# Make UITableView tableHeaderView clear, with all other cells white

Tags: uitableview, jtableheader

My UITableView spans the the size of the iPhone view, with a tableHeaderView holding additional content. Wanting the header to be clear and the rest of the table white, I set the background colour of the table to clear, and inside the view delegate method `-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` I set the cell's background to white.

This takes care of the cells with content, but there's now another problem: data for my table doesn't extend to the bottom, so there are a number of cell spaces that are clear.

I'm just looking for a clear tableHeaderView and white cells. Am I approaching this wrong? Setting the table background to white and the headerView to clear doesn't solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a work around which seems to at least work well enough:

- Set the background colour of the `UITableView` to clear.
- Set the background colour of cells to white in delegate method `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`
- Return a `UIView` with clear background as the header view.
- Return a `UIView` with white background as the footer view and dynamically adjust its height with respect to the number of cells you have. That is, `tableView.frame.size.height - (rowHeight * numberOfRows + headerHeight)`

Answer (score 0):

I have another idea that I tried today and works. I made my tableView's background colour as `[UIColor clearColor]` and I put a scroll view behind the header view. My solution is to make sure that the scroll view that I have behind my table header view has `clipsToBounds` set as `YES`.